# Rails add separate view for child table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a basic application where user has a profile and can upload upto 5 pictures of him/her.I created user profile page, I would want to allow the user to upload pictures in different page. Like having a link Add/Edit Photo and on clicking it to take to a different page and upon submit should redirect back to profile page and update/insert records.  So I'm kind of confused should I do this under photos model/controller  or member model/controller.Here is my sample code and link is below
 I'm using paperclip for image upload
    Member view

```
 <%= link_to 'Add/Edit Photo' , edit_member_path(current_member.id) %>
 <%= form_for(@member, :remote=> true,  html: {
                                    :multipart => true,
                                    class:"form-light padding-15"}) do |f| %>
   <%= f.label :firstname %>
   <%= f.text_field :firstname, autofocus: true, :class => "form-control",:placeholder   =>"FirstName" %>

   <%= f.label :lastname %>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname,autofocus: true, :class => "form-control",:placeholder =>"LastName"%>

 <% end %> 

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :user_id, :dob,:gender,:l_country_id,:age,
  :l_state_id,:l_city,:g_country_id,:residency_status,:marital_status,
  :community,:sub_community,:height,:weight,:complexion,:body_type,
     :diet,:smoke,:drink,:education,:working_as,:working_with,:mobile_no,:about_yourself,:disability,:photos_attributes


 has_many :photos
 belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :state
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

end


class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  has_attached_file :data, :styles => { :thumb => "100x100#",
 :medium => "500x500#",
 :large => "700x700>" },
 :url => "/assets/member/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
   :path => ":rails_root/public/assets/member/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"

 #validates_attachment_presence :data
 validates_attachment_content_type :data, :content_type => /\Aimage/
 #validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 5.megabytes
validates_attachment_content_type :data, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'] 
 attr_accessible :member_id,:data


  end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the separate pages are for photos only, my suggestion is to use PhotosController. And you can use **nested resources** to get the member_id from the url, if that is your concern.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources